# Remove all <select> elements after the one that has been selected

Tags: javascript, select, removechild

I have a list of dynamically generated `<selects>`s in a form. I need to make it so that if the user decides go back to an earlier `<select>`, all `<select>` that come after it will be removed from the page.

My code below will console.log the correct `<select>` elements to be removed, but if I start removing them, then it stops working. I'm looping using a non-live list, so I'm confused about why it's not working as expected.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="select1">square 1:</label>
    <select name="1" id="select1"></select>
    <label for="select2">square 2:</label>
    <select name="2" id="select2"></select>
    <label for="select3">square 3:</select>
    <select name="3" id="select3"></select>
    ...
</form>
```

JS (`select` is the currently selected `<select>`):

```
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    var selects = form.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        if (selects[i].name > select.name) {
            var eleToRemove = selectsLive[selects[i].getAttribute('name') - 1];
            console.log(eleToRemove);
            form.removeChild(eleToRemove.previousSibling); // removes label
            form.removeChild(eleToRemove);
        }
    }
```

Comment: With decides to go back you mean clicking on it? And also with 'come after it' what do you specifically mean?

Comment: When the user clicks on a select, any select with a name value that is larger than that chosen select's name value should be removed

Comment: it's a common issue of modifying collection while enumerating it, and the common solution is to loop backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when it is written correctly

```js
var sel= 2; // for example
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var selects = form.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i = selects.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (+selects[i].name > sel) {
        var eleToRemove = selects[i];
        console.log(eleToRemove);
        form.removeChild(eleToRemove.previousElementSibling); // removes label
        form.removeChild(eleToRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I click on the first select, the 2nd gets removed, but the 3rd doesn't get removed.

Comment: @briennakh, correct, I changed direction of a for loop